# custom menu contains language and menu with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I want to achieve html layout something like this, using Twitter bootstrap

i want it to be responsive, in both mode, desktop and mobile, like example below

desktop mode

[image: desktop]

mobile mode

[image: MOBILE]

This is code I tried so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header >
   <div id="navbar-main">
   <!-- Fixed navbar -->
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Xgp.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li ><a href='#'>FR</a></li>
         <li ><a href='#'>EN</a></li>
         <li ><a href='#'>KR</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role="menu">
         <li><a href='#' >HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href='#' >ABOUT US</a></li>
         <li><a href='#' >TEST</a></li>
         <li><a href='#' >TEST</a></li>
         <li><a href='#' >TEST</a></li>
         <li><a href='#' >TEST</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using 100% logo size.

The easiest way to do this to add css `max-width` property to the logo. For example:

```
.navbar-brand img{
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

It will be responsive as the logo will be assigned max-width property which makes logo stretchable.

You can make the width according to what you think suits best to your design.